# Why does being able to analytically continue the solution of an integral mean we can continue the integral itself?

Tags: gaussian-integral, analytic-continuation

So I am a physicist and have just started a phd related to qft, we often have integrals of the following form:
$$
\int dx\ e^{imx^2}
$$
which is undefined.  However if we take the standard gaussian integral
$$
\int dx\ e^{-ax^2}=\sqrt{2\pi/a}
$$
this can be analytically continued to $a\to -ia$ and hence we can get an answer for the first integral.

Why does this give us a solution to the first integral, why, just because the solution can be analytically continued, does it mean we can continue the integral itself?

Answer (score 1):

Actually $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{imz^2}\; dz$ does exist as an improper integral for real $m$, i.e.
$$ \int_{-A}^B e^{imz^2}\; dz = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{-4im}} (\text{erf}(\sqrt{-im} B) + \text{erf}(\sqrt{-im} A))$$
and the limit of this as $A,B \to +\infty$ is $\sqrt{i\pi/m}$.
The fact that this is the same as the limit of
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{imz^2}\; dz$ as $\text{Im}(m) \to 0+$
involves an interchange of limits whose validity  is not obvious, but can be proven.